# classification of simple singularities for the henselian of the plane Zariski local ring at the origin

Tags: singularity-theory

Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x, y]_{(0, 0)}=\{\frac{f(x, y)}{g(x, y})\in \mathbb{C}(x, y)\ |\ g(0, 0)\neq 0\}$ be the Zariski local ring at the origin. Then the henselisation $A^h$ of $A$ is the ring of formal power series $f(x, y)\in \mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$ such that $f$ is algebraic over $A$.

Now given an element $f$ of $A^h$. Suppose it defines a simple singularity. My question is whether the classification is of ADE type, that is, 
$$\begin{array}{rl} A_n, n\geq 1 & f(x, y)=x^2+y^{n+1}\\
 D_n, n\geq 4 &  f(x, y)=x^2y+y^{n-1}\\
E_6 &f(x, y)= x^3+y^4\\
E_7& f(x, y)=x^3+xy^3\\
E_8 & f(x, y)=x^3+y^5\end{array}$$

I know that the same classification works for the formal power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$ and the convergent series ring $\mathbb{C}\{x, y\}$.

Comment: Your description of $A^{\rm{h}}$ (based on Artin approximation) is not quite right: you have to replace "integral" with "algebraic" (i.e., the root of a nonzero polynomial in $A[t]$ that is not necessarily monic).

Comment: I am reading the book  Plane algebraic curves by Brieskorn and Knoerrer. In Section 8.1, it is said that the ring $A^h$ above is the henselisation of $A$. Do you mean that this is an error?

Comment: Yes, that is an error (but by Artin approximation, which applies much more widely than affine space, it becomes correct if one replaces integrality with algebraicity).  Think about an finite etale cover $E \rightarrow U$ of a Zariski-open neighborhood $U$ of the origin in the plane with degree $d > 1$, and pick points $e, e' \in E$ over 0.  Pick a function $f$ on $E$ that vanishes at $e'$ but not at $e$. Then $1/f$ belongs to $O_{E,e}$ but is *not* integral over $O_{\mathbf{C}^2,0}$ (since it is not regular at $e'$), yet $O_{E,e}$ lies inside the henselization $\mathbf{C}\{x,y\}$.